# defining alias for nameserver

Tags: dns, nameservers

I need your guidance with this issue.
I am currently using a nameserver provided by service provider ***ns1.serviceProviderNameserver.com***
I wish to create my own nameserver ***ns1.myDomainNameServer.com*** and **alias it on top of** ***ns1.serviceProviderNameserver.com***

such that in whois information for my domin, i can **use my own nameserver** ***ns1.myDomainNameServer.com*** and whenever my service provider change the ip addres of its nameserver ***ns1.serviceProviderNameserver.com***, i do not have to change anything from my end.

Your guidance on this would be invaluable.

-Rishabbh

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the root zone only admits A records for your nameservers (in following with [RFC2181](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2181) section 10.3).  Depending on your application, it might be worthwhile to set up a monitoring script that checks to see if your provider's host record has changed, alerting you when it does and allowing you to submit a change for your WHOIS record.